# How do I style FullCalendar to make better use of space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm in the process of implementing an activity calendar for a nursing home that will be printed on sheets of LEGAL sized paper. I'm having a difficult time making everything fit into the calendar, but this is because FullCalendar renders events on a row-by-row basis for each week of the month. This is resulting in a ton of whitespace as seen in my image example below:

[image: Full Calendar whitespace example]

Is it possible to make Full Calendar treat each day as it's own table, and render these events similar to the way that Pinterest renders links, where there's the exact same amount whitespace between events, instead of one day with a long event affecting the entire row?

[image: Pinterest Whitespace Example]

Here's the CSS I'm using right now for this calendar.

```css
html {
 height: 100%;
}

body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0px;
 font-family: 'Tinos', serif;
}

h2 {
 font-weight: 700;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

#activitiesCalendar {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.fc-time {
   display : none;
}

.fc-day-grid-event .fc-content {
 white-space: normal;
 font-size: 11pt;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.fc-day-grid-event {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
 border-color: #000;
 color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this issue has caught the attention of the FullCalendar developers, and there looks to be hope on the horizon. See this Github ticket for more info: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2853

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own view from scratch. For more information refer [doc](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/). I will suggest to check [source](https://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar) for implementation of [Month view](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/basic/MonthView.js) and [Basic view](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/blob/master/src/basic/BasicView.js).

Comment: I've reviewed the docs for this, but am still in the dark as to how exactly I would do this. Can you provide some example code showing what this would look like in practice?

Comment: My requirement were met by default views, however you can start by going through the current implementation of month view. see my edit for links.

Comment: OK. I'll start digging and see what I come up with. Not ready to mark this as the accepted answer until I figure out the code involved in solving this problem.

Comment: Still haven't found a good solution to this problem. Right now to work around this, I'm merging everything into one event per day. So dirty, but I don't know another way yet.